# Laravel 4 - get data from multiselect form

Tags: forms, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent, multi-select

I'm using Laravel 4, and I have two tables related 'Many to many': 'Actividad' and 'Material'. Every Actividad can have one or more Materials, and every Material can belong to one or more Actividad.

So, I have made a form to create a new Actividad where you can save one or more Materials. I've done that with a multiselect input. Like that:

```
{{ Form::label('material_id', 'Material necesario:') }}
<p>{{ Form::select('material_id', $material_id, Input::old('material_id'), array('multiple')) }}</p>
```

I don't know if I'm doing correctly but, before saving anything, my first problem is that I'm only obtaining one result. I suppose I should get every option 'checked' in the form... The relevant part of my Controller is:

```
$material = Input::get('material_id');

return var_dump($material);
```

I should obtain a list of options selected, but the result of that in my browser is:

> string(1) "1"

This is the first time I'm working with tables related in this way, and probably I'm doing something wrong (in the form, in my controller, in my Models,...)

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You need to pass `materials[]` array instead of single `material_id`. What's `$material_id` that you pass to the form select?

Comment: Thank you dczo, you were right about to pass the array!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to this

```
{{ Form::select('material_id[]', $material_id, Input::old('material_id'), array('multiple')) }}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom response handlers on the client side such in the case of submitting info with AJAX, all you need to do is to simple add "[]" to the name of the select control.

e.g.

```
<select name="material_id[]" multiple>
```

This is the same case as with regular PHP. The other methods are required if you want Laravel to handle the form elements for you when rendering a new response/view. ( page reload ). This reload doesn't happen with REST requests.